# Object in bean constructor empty

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have exception-messages written down in the `application.yml`. They are pure text, which is later reformatted using `java.text.MessageFormat`.

I have got the following custom `RuntimeException` my service throws when login failed:

```
@Component
public class AccountLoginFailedException extends RuntimeException {
    @Autowired
    public AccountLoginFailedException(@Value("#(${authservice.exception-messages.login-failed})") final String message, @Qualifier(value = "Credentials") final Credentials credentials) {
        super(MessageFormat.format(message, credentials.getUsername()));
    }
}
```

My test, which solely tests the `AccountController` and mocks away the service behind it:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AuthServiceTestConfiguration.class)
@WebMvcTest(AccountController.class)
public class AccountControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private TestHelper helper;

    @MockBean
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void test_LoginFailed_AccountDoesNotExist() throws Exception {
        // Given

        final Credentials credentials = helper.testCredentials();
        final String credentialsJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(credentials);

        final AccountLoginFailedException loginFailedException = beanFactory.getBean(AccountLoginFailedException.class, credentials);

        // When
        given(accountService.login(credentials)).willThrow(loginFailedException);

        // Then
        mvc
               .perform(
                       post("/login")
                                     .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                                     .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                                     .content(credentialsJson))
               .andExpect(status().isUnprocessableEntity())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data").value(equalTo(loginFailedException.getMessage())));
    }
}
```

`message` contains the correct `String`. **However:** `credentials` contains just an empty object (not null) instead of the one created using `helper.testCredentials()`.

Here is a slightly simplified `TestHelper` class I am using:

```
@TestComponent
public class TestHelper {
    public static final String        USERNAME             = "SomeUsername";
    public static final String        PASSWORD             = "SomePassword";

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    public Credentials testCredentials() {
        final Credentials credentials = beanFactory.getBean(Credentials.class.getSimpleName(), Credentials.class);
        credentials.setUsername(USERNAME);
        credentials.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        return credentials;
    }
}
```

These custom exceptions are thrown by my application only and are always expected to contain the credentials (username) responsible for it. I also have a `AccountExceptionsControllerAdvice`-class, which just wraps these custom exceptions in a generic JSON response, exposing the error in a preferred manner.

**How can I ensure that this particular instance of `Credentials` is inserted into the particular instance of `AccountLoginFailedException`? Or should I not be autowiring exceptions at all?**

Answer (score 0):

You could mock your `Credentials` component in your tests as follows:

```
    @MockBean
    private Credentials credentials;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        when(credentials.getUsername()).thenReturn(USERNAME);
        when(credentials.getPassword()).thenReturn(PASSWORD);
    }
```

Comment: It does not feel right to mock TOs. Is there really no other way?